# Color of wire twists (Marrettes)

Tags: wiring

Quick question again. I used to teach so always on a learning quest. Ok. The wire twists come in various colors. I have used yellow most of the time. But when I check the max for the different colors it seems I could use the yellow or red to twist together two 12 gauge and a double pole thermostat wire. Which is the better way to go? Thanks

Comment: And I meant “marette”

Comment: Usually they have a range of wire gauges, so a smaller one might do two 12 gauge, but it would at the maximum amount for that colour, while the size up would have those two wires in the middle of it's range.  Middle is usually better than pushing it.

Comment: There is no better as they are the same to code. I recently started suggesting wago lever lock splices as they are basically foolproof, you strip the wire lift the wire put it and flip the lever and the wire is locked, no skill required many times over the years I have been called in to troubleshoot a intermittent problem that was a bad splice as wire nuts take a little skill and or attention to detail that lever locks don’t require. I would disagree that the max in the case of 2 wires is pushing it this is a solid bite on the wire the same as the larger size no difference when used as listed

Comment: Thanks again. Have an electrician coming over for the baseboard heaters to see if we can fish wthe 12/2 wires if I put the thermostat in another location

Answer (score 1):

The different colors of wire nuts (or [Marrettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist-on_wire_connector), depending where in the world you are) take a range of different numbers and sizes of wire, which is generally listed on the packaging (different brands can vary slightly for the same colors, though they are similar.)

Where two sizes are **both suitable** for a particular combination & number of wires, they are both suitable for that combination of wires - it really does not matter which you use, in that case. One is not "better" than the other.

One does need to be careful of the colors used twice, but they are generally obvious (a small blue and a big blue are used for such different sizes of wire that you'd really have to be trying to make a mistake to confuse them.)

Answer (score 1):

You know that the wire nut boxes display a simple "range chart". But that's *not* how UL approves them.

UL approves them for [*a detailed and exhaustive list of every combination permitted*](https://rexel-cdn.com/products/file1033idealconnectorullistedwirecombinations.pdf?i=416EA8D6-250E-4489-AD1A-E9193F9E68E4).  Such as:

- One #14 with one to four #12
- One #14 with one to three #10
- One #14 with one to two #8
- One or two #14 with one #6
- Two #14 with one to three #12 or #10

and on and on for miles. This entails a great deal of testing since they are approved for both solid and stranded in any of these combinations.

So to be sure, you need to find that sheet appropriate to your wire nuts, and look up the specific combinations.

However, it is best to work "in the middle of range" for a given wire nut. The ranges have a lot of overlap.  If you are tying four #12 wires, use the nut that takes 2-6 #12, not the one that takes 2-4 #12.   When you work at the extreme of range (high or low) it's *much* more difficult to get a solid connection that passes a pull test.